# Ubuntu 19.04 Audio settings are not being rembembered

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 19.04

I am running almost fresh installation of Ubuntu 19.04 and my audio settings are not getting remembered.

I have disabled one of the speakers (left/right balance) and changed global volume. After each reboot everything is back to default – balance between speakers is at 50%, so is volume level.

I already tried to delete some pulse realted files from `.cache`, `.config` and `.local.share`.

I suppose you will need some additional info, so let me know what commands should I run and I will deliver as soon as possible :-)